# Classifying subgroups of $\mathbb{Z}^n$ up to isomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, reference-request, cyclic-groups, group-isomorphism

I believe that the only subgroups of $\mathbb{Z}^n$ up to isormorphism are $\{0\}$ and $\mathbb{Z}^m$, with $m\leq n$.

This because if $z\neq 0\hookrightarrow H<\mathbb{Z}^n$ so $\langle z\rangle\sim \mathbb{Z}\hookrightarrow H$.

However, I'd like to get this formally (for instance, by a result on a lemma or a more formal proof). Could you help me?

Thank you so much

Comment: Do you know the classification theorem for finitely generated abelian groups?

Comment: @Arthur I did not know (or forgot), but Shaun said bellow, thank you so much!

Comment: Do you mean up to automorphism of the containing $\mathbb{Z}^n$?  Or just up to "internal" isomorphism between the subgroups themselves?  In the former case, Smith normal form implies that for any subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}^n$, there is an automorphism of $\mathbb{Z}^n$ mapping the subgroup to $d_1 \mathbb{Z} \oplus d_2 \mathbb{Z} \oplus \cdots \oplus d_n \mathbb{Z}$ where $d_1 \mid d_2 \mid \cdots \mid d_n$ (and the values $d_1, d_2, \ldots, d_n$ are uniquely determined).  And then, to tie in with the internal isomorphism answer, the rank of the subgroup is the number of nonzero $d_i$ values.

Comment: @DanielSchepler I thought about isomorphisms between themselves. In fact, I thought about conjugacy classes. However, at this abelian groups, I can think identical up to isomorphism, am I right? Thank you so much for the rich comment also

Comment: By the way, you don't need to specify $\{0\}$ as a special case, since $\mathbb Z^0\cong\{0\}$.

Comment: @Vercassivelaunos, you're right, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $\Bbb Z^n$ is a finitely-generated abelian group, the result follows from the Fundamental Theorem of Finitely-generated Abelian Groups, which is a classification result described in [this Wikipedia article](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finitely_generated_abelian_group).

Comment: Thank you so much. So, once any element of $\mathbb{Z}^n$ is nilpotent, there's no subgroups of form $\mathbb{Z}/\mathbb{Z}n$, so the subgroups must be all of form $\mathbb{Z}^m$, $m\leq n$, is it? Thank you!

Comment: A more conventional way of putting the argument: since $\mathbb{Z}^n$ is *torsion-free* that means that any subgroup is also torsion-free, which implies that the "torsion part" of the decomposition $\bigoplus_{i=1}^k \mathbb{Z} / n_i \mathbb{Z}$ is trivial.

Comment: @DanielSchepler thank you so much!!

Comment: @Quiet_waters "Nilpotent" doesn't really make sense in a group. For that, you need both addition (for "nil", i.e. zero, to make sense) and multiplication (for "potent", i.e. powers, to make sense). And a group doesn't have both. "Torsion" is the conventional word here.

Comment: @Arthur thank you so much, I did not know about this.